# Is there Python SDKs to test if docker exists in Google Container Registry (GCR)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I am trying to check if the docker image, gcr.io/<project_id>/: exists in GCR programmatically using Python.

Are there any SDKs I can use to check this? I know running gcloud command to check works fine but was hoping if there are ways to check programmatically without calling a CLI command.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two libraries in go and python you can use:

go (preferred): https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry

python: https://github.com/google/containerregistry